# JQuery ajax php images not load in result

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination

I am using pagination to get the data using JQuery AJAX. The problem is that other HTML will load properly, but not load the images.

This is JQuery AJAX

```
function nextPagination(pageId,liId,reqID){
     jQuery(".flash").show();
     jQuery(".flash").fadeIn(400).html
                ('Loading <img src="images/ajax-loading.gif" />');
     var dataString = 'pageId='+ pageId+'&reqID='+reqID;
     jQuery.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "loadData.php",
           data: dataString,
           cache: false,
           success: function(result){
                 jQuery(".flash").hide();
                 jQuery(".link a").removeClass("In-active current") ;
                 jQuery("#"+liId+" a").addClass( "In-active current" );
                 jQuery("#pageData").html(result);

           }
      });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the image `src` URLs are correct? Check the Network tab of DevTools to see if it's getting an error trying to load the images.

Comment: Yes, src is correct, but not display the image

Comment: But there are no errors in the console? Do you see the `<img>` elements in the DOM inspector?

Comment: Yes, I see the src code id "http://localhost/moonexport/uploads/7364747a.jpg" but not display in the browser.

Comment: There should be `//` before `localhost`. It should be `<img src="//localhost/moonexport/uploads/7364747a.jpg>`

Comment: Otherwise, it looks for a `localhost` subdirectory of the directory containing the URL.

Comment: I don't understand why you're not seeing errors for that URL in the console. Are you sure you checked there like I said in my first comment?

Comment: It has htpp:// before localhost

Comment: Do you see the `<img>` tag in the DOM inspector? (Why do I have to repeat my questions?)